# Map series group dynamic text in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, dynamic-text, map-series

I am in the process of creating a rather large group of map series in ArcGIS Pro 1.3.1, and am making use of the Dynamic Text to generate page titles.

One of the options under Insert > Dynamic Text is "Page with Count", which gives the page number within the entire count of pages.

[image]

I have grouped my map series into different areas, and would like these numbered per group.  Is there a way to modify the dynamic text strings to display the number in a group rather than overall?

I have grouped by Page Name, which groups them nicely

[image]

but instead of giving me a title "Map Group 1 (1 of 5)" or "Map Group 2 (2 of 3)" etc., it just gives me `"Map Group 1 (1 of 8)" and "Map Group 2 (7 of 8)".

[image]

Comment: I'd create 2 field s, one with total in group, 2nd with sequential no inside group and use expression pointing to this two or better combine them both into single text field (%s %s) etc because two dynamics in 1 line are hard

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? This is the exact question I am looking for an answer to.

Comment: @ElaineStone I don't believe I did solve this one, but I'm afraid it was too long ago to remember if I had any kind of workaround that suited.

Comment: Have you tried what @FelixIP has suggested?